# запись в бинарный файл C

Tags: linux, c, io

Как мне записать в Бинарный файл на Linux длину строки из текстового файла . Неплохо бы узнать как между числами длин строки поставить пробел или "\n" . Все делаю через низкоуровненый ввод-вывод на языке C ( то бишь write open read ) . Плюс к этой теме не понимаю как записать в буфер массив число  . int buf[1024] переменная есть но не знаю как туда занести число len

```
while((stringCT = fgetc(fdCT)) != EOF){
    for(; count > 0 ; count--){
        len = 0;
        while((stringCT = fgetc(fdCT)) != '\n')
            len++;
        write(fdB, len,len);
    }
}
```

Comment: запись числа - это просто `write(fdB, &i, sizeof(i));` -все, готово.

Comment: Спасибо , работает.